# Expand an integer value into a range in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data from a PostgreSQL query in this basic shape:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(`Group` varchar(1), `Months` int, `Value` int);

INSERT INTO Table1
(`Group`, `Months`, `Value`)
VALUES
('A', 11, 137),
('B', 9, 666),
('C', 3, 42);
```

Assume that `Value` does not change for each combination of `Group` and `Month`. What I want to do is, expand the table so that `Months` is a range from 1 to whatever the `Months` value is, for each group. So the output would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE DesiredOutput
(`Group` varchar(1), `Months` int, `Value` int);

INSERT INTO DesiredOutput
(`Group`, `Months`, `Value`)
VALUES
('A', 1, 137),
('A', 2, 137),
('A', 3, 137),
('A', 4, 137),
('A', 5, 137),
('A', 6, 137),
('A', 7, 137),
('A', 8, 137),
('A', 9, 137),
('A', 10, 137),
('A', 11, 137),
('B', 1, 666),
('B', 2, 666),
('B', 3, 666),
('B', 4, 666),
('B', 5, 666),
('B', 6, 666),
('B', 7, 666),
('B', 8, 666),
('B', 9, 666),
('C', 1, 42),
('C', 2, 42),
('C', 3, 42);
```

Is there an easy way to do this with SQL, or am I going to have to bring an outside scripting language into the mix?

Comment: FYI, it should be `"Group"`, `"Months"`, etc. Postgres does not use `\`` for quoting.

Comment: If those queries work for you, you can't be using PostgreSQL

Comment: I built the reproducible example using normal SQL, my apologies.

Comment: `\`` is not normal SQL, that is a `MySQL` specific feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a CTE and you don't need to use a CROSS JOIN.

This will do:

```
SELECT t."Group", m.mnth AS "Months", t."Value"
FROM Table1 t
  INNER JOIN GENERATE_SERIES(1,12) AS m(mnth) ON t."Months" >= m.mnth
ORDER BY t."Group", m.mnth;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you need a time series, you can with Postgres easy make one, by using `generate_series` in an `CTE`.

A `CROSS JOIN` with a `WHERE` clause that only allows months as high as the the Months that are represented in the Base table. Of course you can, if you have a more complicated pattern, you can creaet your own `WHERE" clause

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (
>     SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 12) AS s(Months)
> )
> SELECT t1."Group", CTE.months, t1."Value"
> FROM Table1 t1 CROSS JOIN CTE
> WHERE CTE.months <= t1."Months"
> ORDER BY "Group",months
> ```
>
> ```
> Group | months | Value
> :---- | -----: | ----:
> A     |      1 |   137
> A     |      2 |   137
> A     |      3 |   137
> A     |      4 |   137
> A     |      5 |   137
> A     |      6 |   137
> A     |      7 |   137
> A     |      8 |   137
> A     |      9 |   137
> A     |     10 |   137
> A     |     11 |   137
> B     |      1 |   666
> B     |      2 |   666
> B     |      3 |   666
> B     |      4 |   666
> B     |      5 |   666
> B     |      6 |   666
> B     |      7 |   666
> B     |      8 |   666
> B     |      9 |   666
> C     |      1 |    42
> C     |      2 |    42
> C     |      3 |    42
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4109bc25dca91ec1e1c48438bc7b5c9a)*

Answer (score 0):

Using a sequence table we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 12) AS s(Months)
)

SELECT t1."Group", t2.Months, t1.Value
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t2.Months <= t1.Months
ORDER BY t1."Group", t2.Months;
```